# How to see changes for a mercurial file context?

Tags: python, api, mercurial

I'm currently trying to write a script that will find all the files changed given a certain # in the task description, and I have gotten the script to work for that.  But now I'm trying to sort it by whether the file was added, modified or removed.  I've looked through the [Mercurial API](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi), but I can't find anything that can do what I want.

My code currently uses `repo[revnum].description()` and parses that to find which ones contain the `#`, and if they do, add the file context to a list.
This works fine and I can print a list of files, but I can't find a method to see what was done with each context.  Can anyone help me out here, or point me to some better documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using something similar to what Tim said, although I did still use the API.
I imported commands from mercurial, and then called commands.status(repo.ui, repo, change=revnum)

I captured the output of this, using repo.ui.pushbuffer() and repo.ui.popbuffer() which was in the form

```
A file_path1
R file_path2
R file_path3
A file_path4
M file_path5
```

I parsed this input and sorted it into Add, remove, modify, etc..

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to work with the Mercurial API? It is possible to do what you need by working with the output of `hg log`

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should avoid writing scripts directly using the Mercurial API.  It is better to write your scripts to use the CLI or perhaps even use [`hglib`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PythonHglib).  As stated on the [MercurialApi wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi):

> For the vast majority of third party code, the best approach is to use
>   Mercurial's published, documented, and stable API: the command line
>   interface.

That being said, if you really need to use the API, you can use [`repo.status()`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/file/f694ab54b660/mercurial/localrepo.py#l1334) to find the info you asked about:

```
modified, added, removed, deleted, unknown, ignored, clean = repo.status(revnum-1, revnum)
```